# redirect function does not work . Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The redirect function does not work and if i remove the if else statements it works. Can anybody help me?

```
function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
            );  
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('/site/main_menu','refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($query);` and inspect the value. If it is `FALSE`, figure out why.

Comment: i don't get what is wrong.

Comment: Did you use `var_dump()` as I suggested above? If you did, what were the results?

Comment: The result were NULL something does not work correctly.

Comment: What runs in your code is your `else` clause. It runs because your `$query` doesn't return anything (`null`) or it returns `false`. Check your `membership_model->validate()` for query errors.

Comment: when i run the code it redirect me to the validate_credentials method.

Comment: <?php

class Membership_model extends CI_Model{
 
 function validate()
 { 
  
  $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
  $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
  $query = $this->db->query('memberships');
  if($query->num_rows == 1)
  {
   return TRUE;
  }
 
 } 
 }

Comment: i don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Again, you are getting null from your model function because your query is either not correct or it returns more than 1 row. `if($query->num_rows == 1)`, what if num_rows is not 1? Use `var_dump($query)` before your if statement and provide us with the output.

Comment: Look at the line `$query = $this->db->query('memberships');` It should be `$query = $this->db->get('memberships');` thats why your query is failing

Answer (score 0):

Expanding  Minhaz Ahmed comment, make your model as

```
public function validate(){
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query=$this->db->get('memberships');

        if($query->num_rows == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
```